# Get Column Headers from empty result set with Delphi ADOStoredProc

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures

I run several stored procedures with MS SQL.  When I run the procedures under the MS SQL Server Management Studio, they always return column headers.  I am trying to get this functionality in a Delphi program as well.  Currently, no headers are returned if the data set has no rows.  Using Delphi 7, TADOStoredProc, TADODataset and a string grid:

```
ADOStoredProc1.ObjectView := True;
ADOStoredProc1.Open;
ADODataSet1.Recordset := ADOStoredProc1.Recordset;

// process the first dataset, which contains rows

if not ADODataSet1.IsEmpty then
begin
  AdvGridWorkbook1.ActiveSheet := 0;
  // build grid header
  SetupHeader;
  // build grid detail
  SetupDetail;
end
else
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Returned empty data set for Mapping');
end;

// load the next dataset.  no data rows but MS Studio shows column headers

ADODataSet1.Recordset := ADOStoredProc1.NextRecordset(RecordsAffected);

if not ADODataSet1.IsEmpty then // tests as empty
begin
  AdvGridWorkbook1.ActiveSheet := 1;
  // build grid header - none are returned as IsEmpty = True
  SetupHeader;
  // build grid detail
  SetupDetail;
end
else
begin
// this message is added to my memo field.
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Returned empty data set for Labor');
end;
ADODataSet1.Close;
ADOStoredProc1.Close;
```

Does anyone know how MS got column headers to come back?

The stored procedure is:

```
USE [NG_Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[NG_Checks]  ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NG_Checks] 
    @fiscal_month_year nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @production_date datetime
    declare @start_date datetime
    declare @end_date datetime

    select @production_date = ng_production_release_date
    from ng_common_global_provisioning

    select @start_date = start_date, @end_date = end_date
from ng_common_accounting_fiscal_month
    where fiscal_month_year = @fiscal_month_year

-- this is the 1st dataset returned

    select b.company, b.wo_type, b.wo_code
from ng_accounting_mapping_ng_wo_2_gp b
    where wo_code not in (select wo_code from ng_wo_codes a)

--  this is the 2nd dataset returned
    select a.wo_display_id, a.wo_code, a.labor_revenue, a.labor_cost, 
        a.create_date, a.completion_date, a.finalizing_date, a.wo_status
    from ng_wo_header a, ng_wo_labor_rates b
    where a.wo_code = b.work_order_code
        and a.company = b.company
        and a.wo_type = b.work_order_type
        and a.wo_type in ('RO', 'BS')
        and a.labor_revenue is not null and a.labor_revenue <> 0
        and a.labor_cost is not null and a.labor_cost <> 0
        and a.create_date > @start_date
        and a.create_date < @end_date
        and a.create_date > @production_date
END
```

Comment: OK, don't know if this is kosher, but I removed the test for IsEmpty, and the grid now displays headers!  It bugs me that data is there (column headers) but it tests as empty.  I guess "Empty" means no rows, not a lack of actual information.

Comment: Just as you say! From the reference, the [`IsEmpty`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.IsEmpty) indicates whether the dataset contains no records. So it applies only to a dataset rows, not to its field names. Anyway, you've resolved your problem, so would be fair to post and [`accept your own answer`](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/). It can be helpful for future visitors to quickly find the answer to the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The IsEmpty method tests for actual records containing data, so it doesn't count column headers/field names which is preventing your setupHeader method from being called.

Simply remove the call to IsEmpty (or move it):

```
AdvGridWorkbook1.ActiveSheet := 0;
// build grid header
SetupHeader;

// build grid detail
if not ADODataSet1.IsEmpty then
begin
  SetupDetail;
end
else
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Returned empty data set for Mapping');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had found that, and it does the job now.